# Are angles for vectors always measured from the horizontal?

Tags: vectors, conventions, definition

I have a vector which has been stated to have a force of: 96.0 N at $51.3^\circ$. I had a different answer because I was measuring my angles from the north. By default if an angle is given by itself are we to assume that it is being measured from the horizontal axis?

For example I expected to see: 96.0 N at $51.3^\circ$ (from east/horizontal).

Comment: $\uparrow$ No .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context. For the particular case of force vectors acting on an object, the angle is usually specified relative to the surface it's acting on. This can either be specified from the horizontal (where 0 degrees is directly parallel to the surface and 90 degrees is directly perpendicular to the surface) or from the normal (where 0 degrees is directly *perpendicular* to the surface and 90 degrees is directly *parallel* to the surface). Though both are valid conventions, it's more common, in most textbooks I've encountered, for the angle to be specified relative to the normal. However, this may not necessarily be the case for the particular problem you're working on, so it might be a good idea to ask the assigner of the work what convention they're using (or, if you're reading from a textbook, to look towards the beginning, where such conventions are usually specified).

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that within a single problem, all the vectors should measure their angle from the same plane (horizontal/vertical)? I've a question where some force vectors acting on an object are a mixture of the two, so should one plane be chosen, and all the vector directions derived from that single plane? (e.g. 90-angle to convert) - I suspect you *could* evade this by switching around your sines and cosines but that's messier solution